# Black Scholes Replicating Portfolio Riskfree Asset

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, call, black-scholes-pde

Im having a question about this standard derivation of the Black-Scholes formula:

http://www.soarcorp.com/research/BS_hedging_portfolio.pdf

The paper states

$$C=\Delta S+B$$

and finally $\Delta = C_s$. But what is the value of $B$? Is there a functional form for $B$? I could only think of an implicit solution as $B=C-\Delta S$ (where $C$ and $\Delta$ represent the solved Black-Scholes price and delta).

Comment: You are correct. $B$ is computed as $B = C - \Delta S$ and represents the cash amount required to fund the option and its delta hedge.

Comment: @AntoineConze If one can derive $C$ and $\Delta S$, there should also be a way to derive $B$. If we think of $B=C-\Delta S$ in the Black-Scholes model, this would be a pretty complicated formula so I would be interested in its justification

Comment: Very simple formula in the BS case $B = -e^{-rT}K N(d_2)$. You can also note that $B=-K\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}$, which is quite intuitive since you can view the Call option $(S_T - K)^+$ as being the option of exchanging the stock $S_T$ for a quantity $e^{-rT}$ of risk free asset $A_T = Ke^{rT}$, so that $B$ represents the option delta hedge with respect to $A_0$.

Comment: @AntoineConze Very nice argument, thank you!